# Checkbox onclick Event Handler and show/hide function

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, event-handling

so i am trying to make dynamic checkboxs that will show/hide certain content when clicked.  I have this but cannot get it to work properly:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Checkbox Event Handler</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #myGroup {visibility:hidden} 
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function toggle(chkbox, group) { 
            var visSetting = (chkbox.checked) ? "visible" : "hidden"; 
            document.getElementById(group).style.visibility = visSetting; 
        } 
        function swap(radBtn, group) { 
            var modemsVisSetting = (group == "modems") ? ((radBtn.checked) ? "" : "none") : "none"; 
            document.getElementById("modems").style.display = modemsVisSetting; 
        } 
    </script>
    <?php require_once("/var/www/html/exercise/Task/functions.php"); ?>
</head> 
<body> 
    <?php
        $seqA[]="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";
        $seqA[]="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDD0";
        $seqA[]="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD";
    ?>
    <form>
    <?php
        $i=o;
        foreach($seqA as $seq){
    ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="monitor"onclick="toggle(this, 'myGroup')" />show results
            <span id="myGroup">
     <?php
            $score=rawtransform(950);
            $truecol= getcolor($score,220);
            colorSequence($seq,5/*hit*/,$truecol,4);
        }
      ?>
            </span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

it opens the first string in $seqA normally and works fine however the second checkbox is within the first string ?
Im sure ive done something very stupid, but im new to programming.
Anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that in each `foreach` loop iteration you add element `span` with the same `id` attribute. Set unique IDs, change your JavaScript `toggle` function to address specified `span` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with PHP, but it appears that you are generated multiple `span` elements with the same ID, which would cause the `document.getElementById` to act in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Not unpredictable. It chooses the first one.

Comment: @keune true, but now you are imposing order dependency on your elements, not to mention your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @jbaey no, i just stated that when there are multiple elements with the same id, `document.getElementById` returns the first one. I agree that it's totally bad practise.